# parallel computing using foreach for web scraping

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I want to do parallel computing using foreach instead of for loop, but I don't really know how.

So, what I want to do is to get plain texts from a bunch of webpages, and I have over 3000 links to work on. I need to put all of the texts into a single big file.

I know that for loop would work but it would take a long time that I don't even bother to try it.

My question is then, how to convert the `for` loop into `foreach`?

Here is my for loop:

```
library(RCurl)  
library(XML)  
urls <- scan("file", what = "char", quote = "", sep = "\n")  #a vector that contains 3000+ urls  
corpus=character()                              
for (i in 1:length(urls)) {      #a loop that the following function will operate on each link 
  html=getURL(urls[i],followlocation=T)  
  doc=htmlParse(html,asText=T)
  text=xpathSApply(doc,"//p",xmlValue)      
  corpus=append(corpus,text)       #append all the individual text  
}
```

Comment: You could speed up your loop a lot, if you didn't grow `corpus` in the loop. Use `lapply`/`sapply` or pre-allocate `corpus`. If you write this with `lapply` and are not using Windows, parallizing it could be as easy as [putting mc in from of it](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html). I'm also not sure if URL access can be parallelized. You might have to use `getURL` in serial. If you want to use `foreach` you should read the package vignettes. They are quite readable and easy to understand.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @PaulStaab I'm using MacOX

Comment: @Roland Would lapply output a list of texts from the url? Actually I'm not sure if I know how to use lapply, but I'll try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using mclapply:

```
library(RCurl)  
library(XML)  
library(parallel)
urls <- c('http://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com') 

corpi <- mclapply(urls, function(url) {
    html=getURL(url, followlocation=T)  
    doc=htmlParse(html,asText=T)
    return(xpathSApply(doc,"//p",xmlValue))
}, mc.cores=2)
```

and here with foreach and doMC:

```
library(RCurl)  
library(XML)  
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=2)

urls <- c('http://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com') 

corpi <- foreach(url=urls, .combine=c) %dopar% {
    html=getURL(url, followlocation=T)  
    doc=htmlParse(html,asText=T)
    return(xpathSApply(doc,"//p",xmlValue))
}
```

Foreach might be a bit easier to use if you are new to the apply functions. Both should work on OS X and Linux, but not on Windows.

Comment: I tried the doMC with foreach and also doParallel with foreach. I didn't put registerDoMC(cores=2), but put registerDoMC(10). When I tried it with the first 100 links out of my 3000+ links, it ran okay. But when I ran it on the whole thing, I got an error "the process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You must exec()." Is it because I didn't use the cores=2 in registerDoMC?

Comment: I don't think it's the number of cores. I have never tried it on OS X, but here http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/foreach-with-registerDoMC-on-R-2-12-0-OSX-10-6-errors-and-warnings-td3301615.html they suggest running R from the command line instead of using the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is to perform concurrent requests. Take a look at:
?getURIAsynchronous
http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/concurrent.html
This approach however doesn´t always work, but it's worth a try.

```
library(RCurl)

urls = c('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087072/parallel-computing-using-foreach',
         'http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html', 
         'http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf')

opts = list(timeout = 1, maxredirs = 2,
            verbose = FALSE, followLocation = TRUE)

ls_uris <- list()
for(i in seq_along(urls)){
  print(i)
  ls_uris[[i]] <- getURIAsynchronous(urls[[i]], .opts=opts)
}
```